# Sending images from one class to another class (activity to activity)

Tags: java, android, arrays, image, if-statement

I've attached my code below.

It's pretty rough at the minute, I've struggled to get it working.

Basically the user selects an image from a page, then it will load into another (the workout hub).

Here is where I am sending the information (image) I basically want the user to be able to select an image and dynamically add on an image view into the second activity (this is from the first activity)

```
 /**
     *
     */
    protected void loadPullUps(){

        Intent loadPullUpImage= new Intent(this, workout_loader.class);
        //loadPullUpImage.putExtra("pull-ups", byteArray);
        loadPullUpImage.putExtra("pull_ups_var", true);
        startActivity(loadPullUpImage);

    }

    /**
     *
     */
    protected void loadReverseRows(){

        Intent loadReverseRowImage= new Intent(this, workout_loader.class);
        //loadPullUpImage.putExtra("pull-ups", byteArray);
        loadReverseRowImage.putExtra("reverse_rows_var", true);
        startActivity(loadReverseRowImage);

    }

    /**
     *
     */
    protected void loadRackPulls(){


    }
```

This is my second activity where I will load the image into, where I expect the users selections to appear. The first one loadPullups() works, yet from there it crashes if I select another and the code is generally bad. I've spent around 14 hours today trying to get it work and I'm facing a wall.

```
     protected void loadWorkout(){

     /*   int[] myImageList = new int[]{R.drawable.pull_ups, R.drawable.rack_pulls, R.drawable.reverse_rows,
                R.drawable.cable_curls, R.drawable.ez_bar_curls, R.drawable.bicep_curls_exercise, R.drawable.chest_press,
                R.drawable.cable_crossovers, R.drawable.push_ups, R.drawable.tricep_pulldowns, R.drawable.tricep_kickbacks,
                R.drawable.tricep_dips, R.drawable.dumbbell_press, R.drawable.shoulder_shrugs, R.drawable.shoulder_flyes,
                R.drawable.barbell_squat, R.drawable.leg_extensions, R.drawable.leg_press};

*/
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();



        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.container);
       /*for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            ImageView image = new ImageView(this);
            image.setLayoutParams(new android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams(80,60));
            image.setMaxHeight(500);
            image.setMaxWidth(200);

            // Adds the view to the layout
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.pull_ups);

            layout.addView(image);
        }
*/



            if (extras.getBoolean("pull_ups_var")) {
                Log.e("AFTER\t", " " + extras.getBoolean("pull_ups_var"));
                int[] images = {R.drawable.pull_ups};
                int cImage = images[0];
                imgView1.setImageResource(cImage);
            }
            else if (extras.getBoolean("reverse_rows_var")) {
                Log.e("AFTER\t", " " + extras.getBoolean("reverse_rows_var"));
                int[] images = {R.drawable.reverse_rows};
                int cImage = images[2];
                imgView2.setImageResource(cImage);
            }
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send image from one activity to another. You will get `TransactionTooLarge` Exception. Maximum limit for transaction data is around 1 MB and your image will easily overshoot it.

You should send URI of image and reconstruct in another activity.

Comment: How can you do this code? I've looked it up everywhere

Comment: How do you get byte array of image? Can you update your question with that information?